Communicate with graphAPI without app registration in Azure
I know this has been asked here, but I didn't find any solution that could apply to me.
I want to build a Python script that will send events to student calendars, but I do not have permission to register applications in Azure in my school directory, so I cannot even set permissions in the API.
I also tried the ROPC protocol, but it also did not work.
Has someone found a solution to this problem or another way to bypass it?
Then how can other organizations able to interact with office when i use my school account?


Note that: To Communicate with Microsoft Graph API and send events to users via Python script, you require a Microsoft Entra ID application. Refer this SO Thread by Sajeetharan.


Microsoft Graph is a RESTful web API provided by Microsoft, designed to enable developers to interact with a variety of Microsoft Cloud service resources. After registering your application in Azure AD and obtaining authentication tokens for either users or services.
You can use these tokens to send requests to the Microsoft Graph API. This allows you to programmatically access and manipulate data across.
Hence you need to create a Microsoft Entra ID application. To create you need to have Application administrator role. If not contact your administrator.

Create an application and grant below API permissions:

Use the below Python code to create events:
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from azure.identity.aio import ClientSecretCredential

scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']
tenant_id = 'TenantID'
client_id = 'ClientID'
client_secret = 'ClientSecret'

credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id=tenant_id,
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret
)

async def create_event():
   
    token = await credential.get_token(*scopes)
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token.token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    request_body = {
        "subject": "Test",
        "body": {
            "contentType": "HTML",
            "content": "Does next month work for you?"
        },
        "start": {
            "dateTime": "2024-07-10T12:00:00",
            "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
        },
        "end": {
            "dateTime": "2024-07-10T14:00:00",
            "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
        },
        "location": {
            "displayName": "Meeting"
        },
        "attendees": [
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "address": "User@xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "name": "Student"
                },
                "type": "required"
            }
        ],
        "isOnlineMeeting": True,
        "onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"
    }

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/calendars/CalendarID/events', headers=headers, json=request_body) as response:
            result = await response.json()
            print(result)

asyncio.run(create_event())


Or check this PowerShell script to create event for this you must having sufficient permissions. Use Connect-MgGraph -scopes Calendars.ReadWrite and try.
Reference:
Authentication and authorization basics - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft 
